# Displaying XMLType value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, apex

Using Oracle APEX, I want to select raw XML format data as text. Which element should I use?

```
select xmlroot(
    xmlelement("vozidlo",
        xmlattributes(
            a.vyrobne_cislo as "vin",
            a.datum_vyroby as "dat_vyroby"
        ),
        xmlforest(
            c.nazov as "vyrobca",
            a.nazov_modelu as "model",
            a.farba as "farba",
            rtrim(a.kod_motora) as "kod_motor",
            rtrim(a.kod_prevodovky) as "kod_prevodovka",
            d.popis as "typ_karoserie",
            xmlagg(
                xmlelement("zaznam",
                    xmlattributes (
                        g.datum as "datum"
                    ),
                    xmlforest(
                        g.akcia as "popis",
                        g.kilometre as "kilometre"
                    )
                ) order by g.kilometre
            ) as "zaznamy"
        )
    )
, version '1.0') result
    from vozidlo a
    join model b on a.typ_karoserie = b.typ_karoserie
        and a.nazov_modelu = b.nazov_modelu
        and a.id_vyrobcu = b.id_vyrobcu
    join vyrobca c on b.id_vyrobcu = c.id_vyrobcu
    join typ_karoserie d on d.id_typu = b.typ_karoserie
    left join (
        select e.vyrobne_cislo, f.datum, f.akcia, f.kilometre
            from vozidlo e, table(e.zaznamy) f) g on g.vyrobne_cislo = a.vyrobne_cislo
        where a.vyrobne_cislo = :P7_VIN_VOZIDLA
            group by a.vyrobne_cislo, a.datum_vyroby, c.nazov, a.nazov_modelu, a.farba, a.kod_motora, a.kod_prevodovky, d.popis
                fetch first row only;
```

Currently I am using dynamic contect element, which is not displaying format properly. Instead of this format

[image]

I am receivng this...

[image]

I have also tried another elements like Textarea but it loads up with error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the XML as XML then you can convert it to a CLOB:

```
xmlroot(xmlelement("vozidlo", ...), version '1.0').getclobval() as result
```

But [XMLRoot is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLROOT.html) so you should be using [XMLSerialize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLSERIALIZE.html):

```
xmlserialize(document xmlelement("vozidlo", ...) as clob version '1.0') as result
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0krQciwH) with (very) simple example.